# How do i connect an Oracle Cloud DB to Intellij Ultimate?

Tags: intellij-idea, oracle11g

Im trying to connect my oralce cloud database to intellij using my wallet.I followed the guide at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/connect-to-oracle-cloud-by-using-wallets.html but i still have some problems.

Once i try to test my database connection i have the following error:

**Incompatible version of libocijdbc Jdbc:211000, Jdbc-OCI:213000**

It seems an error caused, as the error says, by an incompatible version of driver. While preparing of my driver's i downloaded all the requesting files in 21.1.0.0 version.

[image: this is my custom drivers]

[image: this is my data sources configuration]

Comment: Please go to Help -> Show log in explorer -> open idea.log ffile and check -classpath values in latest connection try. Probably you will see where files of v.21.3 are located and then remove them from path.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, I did not have to manually add the driver files and add custom JARs. *Maybe* this is a requirement on your end, but if it is NOT or you only need the latest versions available, you can do the below:

**IntelliJ** offers a feature out-of-the-box for downloading any missing database driver files for you as noted in step 3 [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/oracle.html). To fix this:

1. Remove all the JARs you have added by clicking on `-`
2. Click on the `+` to Add > `Provided Driver` > `Oracle` > Select a Version
3. Click on `Download ver x.x.x.x` where `x.x.x.x` is the available version

Note: I am using `Thin` as the Driver instead of OCI. My `TNS name` is set to one of the available profiles listed in my `tnsnames.ora`.